# Superfish to open an option "onInit"

Tags: jquery, superfish

On some of my pages I want Superfish (menu plugin) to unfold one of the first level options by default as soon as the page opens. I attributed this option ul an id="me", and trying to implement "onInit" function, but it does not work. Could someone please look? Thanks.

```
jQuery(function(){
jQuery('ul.sf-menu').superfish({
    onInit: function(){$('#me',this).show();},
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

do you get any javascript errors?

possible problems with the snippet you posted:

- `onInit` does not get called for whatever reason.  check with `alert` or `console.log`
- `this` in `onInit` is not a DOMElement.  it might be a jquery object.  check with `console.log`

plus, you have a syntax error in there: the last property in an object literal must not be followed by a comma.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I will try to check what you suggested tomorrow (i have Firebug installed but do not know how to use it yet, i am a nub).
Also, I now think I'd better find a way to dynamically pass a "visible" css to this option with PHP in order to have it work with desabled JS?

Comment: there's not much to basic use of firebug (I didn't dig beyond the console and the network traffic monitor [Console and Net tabs]).
yes, if you want to have it working same with or without javascript, you should setup the initial state without javascript.  like, change `#me` to `.open`, have the rest be collapsed with css.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the CSS part was easy. It does not use any "visibility" values, instead it changes
a box position from "top:-999em" (to hide) to "top:2.5em" (to display).
I created a separate class for my , which is just a copy from Superfish "displayable" boxes:

```
ul.open {
left:   0;
top:    2.5em;
z-index:    99;
}
```

Now it works if JS is disabled but when JS is enabled all options get collapsed anyway.
Here is just one of the many variants i tried this time:

```
    onInit: function(){$('ul.open').addClass('ul.open');}
```

and it has no effect at all, as if this class does not exists.

If I try:

```
    onInit: function(){$('ul.open').html('hello');}
```

the word 'hello' appears on mouseover instead of submenu - but on mouseover, not "onInit".